# Zend Framework and keeping all of my code together

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I've added the following to my `application.ini`:

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "DP_"
```

This way, within my controller, I can say `new DP_Form_Login()`, and it will load the form class from `library/DP/Form/Login.php`.  Is there a way then, to make it so that my controller class (which I've now called `DP_Controller_Login`, and placed in to `library/DP/Controller/Login.php` will be called when I access `/login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well really you want all your controllers in the `controllerDirectory`... Likewise you might want to move to `APPLICATION_PATH /forms` as thats the standard place. `library` is typically for things that are more general - think of it as your framework on top of Zend Framework, while the stuff in `application` and `application/modules/$modulename` is application/module specific.

Obviously ZF is flexible enough that you can set your structure up any way you please, but if you go outside the "standard" youre going to have to write a lot of uneeded configuration if not code... Its just easier to play inside the box unless you have a really compelling reason to work outside of it.